# differential equation $y' = \frac{a}{(b+xy)^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation
$$y' = \frac{a}{(b+xy)^2}$$
**My attempt:** Substitution
$$y = \frac{z}{x} \implies y' =  \frac{xz' - z}{x^2} \\ 
\frac{xz'-z}{x^2} = \frac{a}{(b+z)^2}$$
But this doesn't seem to help much.

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%3D%28a%29%2F%28b%2Bxy%29%5E2) says
$$-\frac{\sqrt a \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt b y}{\sqrt a}\right)}{b^{3/2}} + \frac{\sqrt a \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{ b y(b+y)-ax}{\sqrt a b^{3/2}}\right)}{b^{3/2}} + \frac{y}{b} = c_1$$

Answer (score 2):

Change
$$y=u-\frac{b}{x}$$
gives separable ode
$$u'=\frac{a-bu^2}{u^2x^2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Switch variables to make
$$x'=\frac 1a(b+x y)^2$$ which is quite ugly but doable.

You will have $x(y)$ but no way to inverse it. Using a CAS gives the nasty
$$x=\frac{b^{3/2} \left(-c_1 \cosh \left(\frac{\sqrt{b} y}{\sqrt{a}}\right)+i \sinh
   \left(\frac{\sqrt{b} y}{\sqrt{a}}\right)\right)}{\left(\sqrt{b} c_1 y+i
   \sqrt{a}\right) \cosh \left(\frac{\sqrt{b} y}{\sqrt{a}}\right)-\left(\sqrt{a}
   c_1+i \sqrt{b} y\right) \sinh \left(\frac{\sqrt{b} y}{\sqrt{a}}\right)}$$